# How to save a list to a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save a list to a database, however, it has no effect.

Here is my model:

```
    private IList<int> _chatIDs;
    public IList<int> ChatIDs
    {
        get { return _chatIDs ?? (_chatIDs = new List<int>()); }
        set { _chatIDs = value; }
    }
```

Here is the saving part:

```
    MyDbContext myDbContext = new MyDbContext();
    var game = myDbContext.Events.Find(e.ID);
    var newList = game.ChatIDs;
    newList.Add(e.ChatID);
    game.ChatIDs = newList;
    myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Take a step back. How would you map that list in the database? How is it represented? (*There is no native type/data model of a primitive array in a relational database.*)

Comment: Which database are you trying to use? Because some DB-Systems have array-types. eg https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html

Comment: You're approach seems to be something that would require a ForeignKey relationship with the "users in a game" That would would give you a collection of chat ids for "users" in the game. Thinking out loud: dbo.Users, dbo.Games, dbo.UsersInGame would be the tables you could use. create FK on dbo.UsersInGame.UserId > dbo.Users.UserId and dbo.UsersInGame.GameId > dbo.Games.GameId.

Comment: Every event would have many chat IDs, which are just ints. How would I implement that then if there is no primitive array in a relational database?

Comment: There are primitive array-types in rdbs, but that won't help until you model your data for that kind of persistent store. Do you want to persist the events, do you plan to retrieve them by primarykey, do you plan to do joins against other entities in your storage etc.

Answer (score 0):

Database Schema Outline:

### Tables:

- dbo.Users
- dbo.Games
- dbo.UsersInGame
- dbo.ChatSession

### Foreign Keys:

- dbo.UsersInGame.UserId > dbo.Users.UserId
- dbo.UsersInGame.GameId > dbo.Games.GameId
- dbo.Games.ChatId > dbo.ChatSessions.ChatId

Then create collections for these foreign key relationships in your model, something like the following (Sorry I couldn't take the time to write example code, i just took this from a generated entity in one of my current projects):

```
public partial class SecurityUser
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public SecurityUser()
        {
            this.SW_Mobile_Pick_Assignment = new HashSet<SW_Mobile_Pick_Assignment>();
            this.SW_Mobile_Session = new HashSet<SW_Mobile_Session>();
           
        }
    
        public int SecurityUserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Passwrd { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Enable { get; set; }
        public string FileMakerId { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsAccountManager { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsHandHeldAccount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> HandheldPin { get; set; }
        public string Last5SSN { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SW_Mobile_Session> SW_Mobile_Session { get; set; }
}
```